# Looking for a way to take a string and replace every single with two symbols and back again

Tags: php, data-manipulation

I'm trying to figure out a way to take an imported string and replace every character with 2 specified characters and then be able to take the output and run it through another function to bring back the original string.

this is an example of the conversion i'm looking to do

```
@  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O      From
AF AE AD AC AB AA A9 A8 A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0     To

   !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  )  *  +  ,  -  .  /      From
CF CE CD CC CB CA C9 C8 C7 C6 C5 C4 C3 C2 C1 C0     To
```

I would think this would be something along 2 arrays with the to and from in the same order similar to this?

```
$before = array("A","B","C","D","E");
$after = array("AE","AD","AC","AB","AA");

echo someFunction("CAB"); // outputs "ACAEAD"
```

but I can't figure out the best way to go about this. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php).

```
$trans = array("A" => "AE","B" => "AD", "C"=>"AC","D"=>"AB","E"=>"AA");
echo strtr("CAB", $trans); // outputs "ACAEAD"
```

For the reverse function, just [`array_flip`](https://www.php.net/array_flip) the original array.

```
$trans2 = array_flip($trans);
echo strtr("ACAEAD", $trans); // outputs "CAB"
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this:

make an `key=>value` pairs array by `array_combine()` and use `strtr()`

```
$before = array("A","B","C","D","E");
$after = array("AE","AD","AC","AB","AA");
$array =  array_combine($before,$after); // make key value pairs array

echo someFunction($array,"CAB");

function someFunction($arr,$string) {
 return strtr($string, $arr);

 }
```

OUTPUT:  `ACAEAD`

[demo](https://eval.in/107339)

Comment: @TonyBilby : did you try this?

Comment: I did try and your first one didn't but this revision does but I marked arch's answer as the correct one cause he mentioned how to reverse it as well and that was important but I'm going to vote you up for a great alternative as I wasn't aware you could combine arrays like that, that's very useful to know!

Comment: Yup and I am voting you up too because if there already exist `$before = array("A","B","C","D","E");
$after = array("AE","AD","AC","AB","AA");`, `array_combine($before,$after);` in the codes then `array_combine($before,$after);` will be a good way for the array construction.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually pass arrays to `str_replace`

```
$someString = "abc";
$search = array('a','b','c');
$replace = array('ae','ad','ac');
$someString = str_replace($search, $replace, $someString);
```

**EDIT**
https://eval.in/107493

Comment: This didn't work, it kept replacing characters it had already replaced leaving interesting results that were not able to be reversed either.

Comment: ahh I see, you have it echoing before and after on the same line, really throws me off. I do like the approach that arch is taking with $var = array("A" => "AE","B" => "AD"); Since I have a few hundred characters to put into this array, 2 lines will make it a bit confusing.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I added a break between them to make it clearer. I'll post the link on the original answer just in case.